# How to move over

Tags: vb.net, methodology

Uphill about 5 years ago my career was going fairly well, but separation, family deaths and a bit of illness caused me to make a couple of BAD career decisions, and I ended up in a dead end job doing mainly vb 6, though it was the end as mid to late 30, but was recently handed a break, working with a forward thinking vb.net company and I took the chance with both hands, been there 5 months now

Thing are going ok, spending a lot of time in places like this, and reading books, but coming from a C / Machine Code / VB 5 &6 background, I'm finding the little intracity of .NET lost on me, if I write code I wouldn't think to use delegates for example, has anybody got any advice on making the 'brain' VB.NET jump, or training I should be looking at (bear in mind that I'm not rich)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry\, I can't help ypu with the vb.net, but I think I know a bit what you have been going through. Its fantastic to get a new chance and I am fully convinced you are going to make it! Best of luck.

Comment: Ta .. am glad of the new chance, just want to make the most of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a introductory .NET course will be a good investment. It gives you a chance to focus on .NET for four or five days and build a good foundation.

The other choice is to use online resources and do self study. One suggestion (out of the ton that are out there) is to follow one of the webcast series available at http://www.microsoft.com/events/series/modernsoftdev.aspx?tab=webcasts. Although they are a little dates (they focus on Visual Studio 2005) they are designed for people like yourself.

The other suggestion is to find a local .NET user group. Spending some time with people and sharing exeriences will help you learn and will give you a chance to do some networking.

Answer (score 1):

Just work with the .NET framework, and the use of things like delegates or interfaces will come to you. Since you already know that they exist, you will find yourself in a situation where you think *"Gee, this can easily be done by using a delegate!"* If that happens, use a delegate.

I think this is better than looking for a way to use all those shiny .NET thingies - they are useful, but only if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I would suggest not moving to vb.net at all, but instead utilizing your C background, and making the move to C#. The reason for this is, you already know the syntax and that VB.net is not enough like VB6, to make it as easy a move as you might expect. Plus you're more "likely" to come into contact with developer's who use the more advanced features of the framework etc.

This might be a slightly controversial statement but I firmly believe that in order to re-ignite a career it's sometime better take a mental leap to something new. You'll find that everything you've learn prior to this, will cement the new knowledge you'll be acquiring.

In addition find a personal project you can get highly motivated about, with a tangible end goal/deliverable, that will make learning your new skills much more fun.

Answer (score 0):

It's not like C/Machine code programmers aren't in demand... They're growing increasingly rare as developers are breast-fed with Java or .NET nowadays :)

Comment: I fear that my machine code days are over that was 8+ years ago, mainly been vb 6 the last 5+ years .... though could be interesting to pull out a compiler again ... once I've mastered VB.NET